# Able to get the data from api but not able to reflect in the table

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using angular 13.2.6 version and .net core api.

I have to components PaymentdetailsView (parent) and PaymentDetailsForm (child).

In the PaymentDetialsForm, i have a form which on submitted calls the api and data is posted to database.

In the PaymentDetailsview component, the data shall be shown in the table.

The problem is i am not able to load the view component as soon as i submit the form.
The two forms are side by side. And my requirement is that the moment i submit the form the adjacent table should be populated with the updated data.

PaymentView.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { PaymentServicesService } from '../services/payment-services.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-payment-view',
  templateUrl: './payment-view.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./payment-view.component.css']
})
export class PaymentViewComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public http: PaymentServicesService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void
  {
    this.http.getResult();
  }
  getDetails()
  {
    // used just to check if idea is working
    //on click of a button in form this method calls get request and fill the table
  }

}
```

PaymentDetailsForm.component.ts

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { PaymentServicesService } from '../../services/payment-services.service';
import { PaymentViewComponent } from '../payment-view.component';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-paymentdetailsform',
  templateUrl: './paymentdetailsform.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./paymentdetailsform.component.css']
})
export class PaymentdetailsformComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private http: PaymentServicesService) { }
  paymentDetailsId: number = 0;
  cardOwnerName: string = '';
  cardNumber: string = '';
  expirationDate: string = '';
  securityCode: string = '';
  details: any;

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  resetForm(formvalue: NgForm) {
    formvalue.reset();
  }
  submitForm(form: NgForm) {
    this.http.postForm(form).subscribe(res => {
      this.details = res;
      console.log("success");
    }
      , err => console.log(err));
    this.http.getResult();
  }
}
```

PaymentService.service.ts

```
import { HttpClientModule , HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PaymentServicesService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  posturl = 'https://localhost:7272/api/PaymentDetail';
  getUrl = 'https://localhost:7272/api/PaymentDetail';
  list: any;//to store fetched data from db
   
  postForm(form: NgForm) {
     return this.http.post(this.posturl, form.value);
  }


  getResult() {
    this.http.get(this.getUrl).subscribe(res => {
      console.log("service is called");
      this.list = res;
    }, err => console.log(err));
    
  }
}
```

Initially the form loads and the view component also populates the data from db.
After filling the form and submitting it, data is posted to db but view component is not updated. How could I do that?

Comment: Inside the `PaymentdetailsformComponent.submitForm` method, `this.http.getResult()` is called outside of the subscribe handler. Move this call inside the handler (just under `console.log("success");`) and see if this solves your issue.

Answer (score 1):

you should return an Observable in your service, and follow more or less this guide :
https://angular.io/guide/http

```
getConfig() {
  // now returns an Observable of Config
  return this.http.get<Config>(this.configUrl);
}
```

And in your component, you subscribe to this, or even better, you use async pipe.
https://yon.fun/angular-http-best-practices/